# Rails Asset Pipeline to a Grunt based approach

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, gruntjs, asset-pipeline, grunt-contrib-concat

I wish to try out Grunt so for a task I have duplicated a project and want to convert it from using the default asset pipeline to work all via Grunt and it's tasks.

I can then evaluate both approaches and go for what I think turns out the best.

I have disabled the pipeline in my `application.rb` file. I have set up my `Gruntfile.js` and want to first of all get it to concatenate my javascript files. I am using the `grunt-contrib-concat` task but what I cannot figure out is the best place to tell grunt to place the processed files?

Would it be in `/public`?    I am just confused as to where these files will now be served from?    I know that I cannot use the Rails asset helpers in my views and will have to reference them myself, but from where?

I hope you can help.

Comment: Are you writing your backend in RoR or node.js?

Comment: It's in Ruby on Rails

Comment: Still unsure if this is right but for now I am outputting them to /public/assets